# Adding a wildcard in Query where clause? (Access '16)

Tags: where-clause, criteria, ms-access-2016

My Query pulls records based on a few different unbound fields in a search form. For the searchable fields, I use the following in the criteria second of each query field:

```
Like Nz([field_in_search_form], "*")
```

For the Name field, I'd like the end user to type "Tony" and get results such as "Tony", "Tony B.", "Tony Bacon", "Tony Bacon and Alfred Ham", etc.

Is there a way to do this using wildcards in the criteria? Another IT guy recommended I set the field as a local variable and then add the wildcard to the variable, but I haven't been able to search for that on the web in a way that's helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with (SQL):

```
Select * From YourTable
Where [YourField] Like [field_in_search_form] & "*"
```

If Null should be included:

```
Select * From YourTable
Where ([YourField] Like [field_in_search_form] & "*") Or ([field_in_search_form] Is Null)
```